# How to define new cite command just like \nocite but prints missing citation entry?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to have a cite command `\mycite` as

1. `\mycite{exist-entry}` just works like `nocite{exist-entry}`
2. `\mycite{not-exist-entry}` would show **not-exist-entry** in the document

But I do not know how to define such a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already a get a good warning in the `.log` file about missing references even with `\nocite`, but here is a definition that has almost the same properties as `\nocite` when the entry key does exist and that prints the key in bold if it doesn't.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mynocite}[1]{%
  \blx@xsanitizeafter{\forcsvlist\mynocite@do}{#1}}
  
\newcommand*{\mynocite@do}[1]{%
  \nocite{#1}%
  \blx@ifdata{#1}
    {}
    {\abx@missing@entry{#1}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\mynocite{sigfridsson}

\mynocite{does-not-exist}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: does-not-exist]

Answer (score 0):

The following will replace the **?** in a citation for an undefined bib label with the text of the label when you use `\cite`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries \@citeb}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

As a less intrusive approach, you could always do something like `grep 'Citation.*undefined' yourdocument.log` to get a list of undefined citations in your document.